# How to mock DOM object in Js?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add some unit tests to test UI of some javascript. However I don't want to use HTML page, I would like to use node.js.

Is there any js library which I can use to mock HTML DOM, like document?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, You can use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) for this. It is what facebook's [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) framework uses behind the scenes to run tests on components that use DOM via node.

Comment: It looks like jsdom does not work with node.js any more?

Comment: @AdamLee newer versions of jsdom do not but you can just use the 3.x version until node gets up to speed (since node and io are going to merge).

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using a headless browser. Depending on your technology stack there are multiple options. When using [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) A popular one is [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/). There're different test runners for different test frameworks, here's an [overview](http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html) of them.

[mocha.js](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mpchajs) is a popular testing framework which has a [phantom.js test runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-phantomjs).

If you're using [browserify](http://browserify.org/) there's also [mochify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochify) which works really nice.

There's also [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) but one caveat with that one is that it only works with [io.js](https://iojs.org/en/index.html) from v4.0.0.